# Error in node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Modal/Modal.js while testing with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I'm making a simple snapshot test with Jest and just get this error: [image]

**home.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './index';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders home', ()=> {
  const view = renderer.create(
    <Home></Home>
  ).toJSON();
  expect(view).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Unfortunately I don't have idea what is the problem here. I thought the test is well written.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HOW I SOLVED THE ERROR KEEPING MY TEST FROM RUNNING

Ran into this error, which kept my tests from running

￼[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUWmE.png)

After many hours of frustration, in which I deleted the *node_modules* folder twice and reinstalled and scoured through Stackoverflow and Google without any solution, I decided to create a new CRNA project and see if it would have the same issues. 
When I saw the issues didn’t exist in the new repo, I used the following steps to get it to work:

1. Delete the node_modules folder again
2. Upgraded my package.json file, with the key changes shown below:

```
{

```
"devDependencies": {
        "react-native-scripts": "1.5.0",
        "jest-expo": "^21.0.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
    },


"jest": {
        "preset": "jest-expo",
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
                "node_modules/(?!react-native|expo|react-navigation|native-base-shoutem-theme|@shoutem/theme|@shoutem/animation|@shoutem/ui|tcomb-form-native)"
         ]
    },


"dependencies": {
                "react-native": “0.48.4”,
        "expo": "^21.0.2",
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
    },
```

`3. The core difference was in upgrading react-native from 0.48.0 to 0.48.4; react-native-scripts from 1.2.1 to 1.5.0 and including the transformIgnorePatterns under the jest option.
NOTE: The portion from *native-base* in the transformIgnorePatterns was included because I used NativeBase in the project. 
4. I then added a .babelrc with the following details:`

```
{
        "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
        "env": {
                "development": {
                    "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
             }
         }
    }
```

```
5. Running the tests now give me the result:

￼[Passing Tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLEDd.png)
All tests are green

Comment: What CRNA means?

Comment: CRNA: create-react-native-app.